# Calculated Field in Archer Subform

Tags: archer, rsa-archer-grc

I just created a subform to have users upload documents. Within the subform, I created a numeric field for users to provide the document's version number. From there, I want a calculated field that would populate to indicate if the document is the most recent or not. I built the below calculation, but it seems like the "MAX" function doesn't actually pull the maximum number from all of the subform entries, so it doesn't really work.

I created a calculated field that is outside of the subform that grabs the MAX version number, but I can't actually reference that field from within the subform.

Below is the calculation:

```
IF([Version]=MAX([Version]),VALUEOF([Type],"Most Recent"),VALUEOF([Type],"Previous"))
```

1. Can anyone assist with the formula?
2. Is there a better way to automatically have the most recent subform entry be named "Most Recent"?

Answer (score 1):

Max to get the max number from a field in the sub-form use the REF() function inside the MAX() function like so,

```
MAX(REF([Sub-From Field Name],[Version]))
```

Also, take a look at the MOSTRECENTVALUE() function.

Comment: Thank you for this. Having trouble with the REF formula. What would would the "[Sub-From Field Name]" be from as "[Version]" is a field within the subform.

Comment: The [Sub-Form Field Name] is the name you gave the sub-form field when you added it to the parent application. If you go to the Formula Builder, locate the sub-form field click the [+] to expand it and select the Version field.  It should build the REF() function for you.

Comment: Hmm. It's not showing. The field I'm trying to calculate is within the subform field, so there's no [+] within the formula builder--only the fields created in the subform.

Comment: Unfortunately, what you're looking to do isn't going to work.  Sub-forms cannot see all of the records that are created in the application.  Only the parent application can see all the sub-form records. If you do the calculation at the parent level it will work, but the sub-form cannot reference the calculation in the parent record.  To only way to get it to work is to use an on-demand application instead of a sub-form.

Comment: Understood. Thank you!